# Responsive theme (WP) - change the order of elements in a page

Tags: php, wordpress

Hello members of the forum

I have a WordPress site with a responsive theme.
here is an example of a relevant page:
http://www.kastach.co.il/lorem-ipsum-page

I use a widget of a small search form: widget_mfn_infopay

when I enter an inside page like the above example, from a cellular devise or a small resolution device the responsive theme fires but the CONTENT section is above the widget.
So a user needs to scroll all the way to the bottom of the page to reach the widget area.
how can I change the order of the page only for cellulars, so that the widget is **above** the content?

I will appreciate any help,
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should have to just change the placement of the content div and the widget div
Place widget div before the content then it will show above the content in small resolution

```
<div class="four columns">widget</div>
<div class="content">content</div>
```

Comment: Hi Afaan, How can I locate the exact file that I need to change? I cant see it from firebug.(sorry for a newbie question).

Comment: you don't know about file location ? Please check page.php may you find.

Comment: Hi again there is no <div class="four columns">widget</div>
<div class="content">content</div> in page.php

Comment: can you show me your `page.php` or `index.php` files

Comment: [page.php](http://www.kastach.co.il/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/page.php_.txt) and [index.php](http://www.kastach.co.il/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/index.php_.txt)

Comment: ok thanks i checked page.php file so i need `content-page.php` or `content.php` in the include folder of the theme...

Comment: here is [content-page.php](http://www.kastach.co.il/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/content-page.php_.txt) Thanks a lot.

Comment: email? stevenharder51 @ yahoo.com